# React component with dangerouslySetInnerHTML, contain CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a React component that renders this element:

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.props.htmlString}}/>`

It works fine, and the html is being rendered. However, the issue that I'm having is that my client code has CSS in place, which is reaching into the component that I'm rendering from `this.props.htmlString`. Is there a way to prevent my client CSS code from being applied to this component?

Comment: This sounds like a typical issue with global CSS. If you use styled CSS or CSS Modules it might solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to target the element in your CSS and override the styles that you don't want to be applied.

Comment: Sigh...That's what I thought. Fortunately, there are only like 3-4 properties that I need to stop from being inherited but I sure wish there was a way to just stop inheritance from a parent container and use default values instead. Maybe a good idea for a side project later on..